# Add floating listview in middle of screen layout in android

Tags: android, listview, runtime, floating

I have an input screen in my app and I have an Edittext on it and on entering some text in this Edittext  I need to add a floating listview in middle of screen layout in android on runtime. How to add this floating listview in middle of screen on runtime.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Munazza

Comment: Why do you want the floating ListView? Are you trying to create an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_I2Ctfz7eew4/S-fuCsktkaI/AAAAAAAAAZw/31QDXkXQ_Yc/s1600/AutoCompleteTextView2.1.PNG)?

Comment: yeah, i want to populate that listview with email addresses from phonebook that match best with the text as I start entering an email in that edit text.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want an AutoCompleteTextView that works with your contacts, then try [this tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/).